# Does unreachable code within #ifdef and #endif get removed during compile/link time?

Tags: c++, c

Does unreachable code within #ifdef and #endif get removed during compile/link time or kept in the executable even though it can not be reached?

```
#ifdef DEBUG
// some debug operations
#endif
```

Is the debug operation code still kept after compilation without DEBUG flag, and if it is will it affect the performance of release build?

EDIT:

If there were some modules used only in the debug operation, and if it is linked into the program, will this affect the performance?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The preprocessor will completely remove such code - the compiler doesn't even get to see it.

You can e.g. use `g++ -E` to have a look at what the preprocessor does, and what the compiler gets to see.

Comment: If there were some modules used only in the debug operation, and if it is linked into the program, will this affect the performance?

Comment: @Atomble: Depends on your definition of modules, and how they're linked. An unneeded DLL would reduce application startup time by a very small amount of time. But code that isn't executed won't affect the run-time performance of your app.

Comment: @Atomble: Assuming the debug modules aren't huge enough to cause memory to be swapped out, no. Linking in unused modules won't affect performance in the slightest.

Comment: say that I have a unit test module, it was compiled into unittest.o and it was just static linked to main.o

Comment: @Atomble: If it's unused it's very likely that the linker completely removes it. Either way, it wouldn't matter for performance.

Answer (score 1):

It's removed by the preprocessor (with an external preprocessor, blank lines are usually substituted).